# Connect Java to MS SQL Server Database using Windows Authentication

Tags: java, database

I have found some similar questions but with no helpful answers.
   I need to manipulate an MS SQL Server database named PDPJ_Student from my java application and i cannot connect to it. I get the following error:

[Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Login failed for user 'LAPTOP-TITI/Titi'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

and my source looks like this:

```
Connection con = null;
try{
   Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LAPTOP-TITI;DatabaseName=PDPJ_Student", "LAPTOP-TITI/Titi", "");
  }
  catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Error at connection");
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

When i start MS SQL Server, at authenticatin, the SERVER NAME says: LAPTOP-TITI; and the Authentication is set to Windows Authentication. The user name field says LAPTOP-TITI/Titi but it is disabled, as well as the Password field, which is empty.

I have also tried:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LAPTOP-TITI;DatabaseName=PDPJ_Student", integratedSecurity=true);
```

but still nothing ..

What am I doing wrong ? Can you give me some indications please?

p.s I am not allowed to change my Authentication type, and even if I try changing to SQL Server Authentication, it doesn`t let me create any new users

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't mention whether your client machine is running Windows or non-windows. [This topic on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/ffd3265b-61cc-4091-ab3b-a7b87dd6f035) suggests that if your client is using Linux, you'll need to purchase the [DataDirect](http://web.datadirect.com/products/jdbc/index.html) driver to get Kerberos authentication working. If you're on Windows, it should be possible with Microsoft's JDBC driver.

Comment: It`s running under Windows Xp and I set into the project`s classpath the msbase.jar, mssqlserver.jar and msutil.jar .... That should be enough to get java working with MS SQL Server